# Solving a basic equation for calculating weight of fish from length of fish? $W = 0.00208 + L^{2.577}$ for $L$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is the typical form for calculating the weight of a fish from the length ("fork" length or total length). How can I re-arrange this equation to solve for L?

$$W = 0.00208 + L^{2.577}$$

Comment: Oh - thanks... OK, I will adjust the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question may not be directly about logarithms, but you can certainly find the solution using logarithms rather conveniently.

Start with the original: $W-0.00208 = L^{2.577}$, then take natural logs of both sides and you get:
$$\ln(W-0.00208) = 2.577\ln(L),$$
at which point you have:
$$\frac{\ln(W-0.00208)}{2.577} = \ln(L).$$
And then you can finish by inverting the log.
$$L = \exp\left(\frac{\ln(W-0.00208}{2.577}\right).$$

Note this is equivalent to writing that $L = (W-0.00208)^{1/2.577}$, which is the solution you would get if you followed the trail avoiding logarithms.

Comment: Please read [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards), which applies to poor questions, and importantly, those who answer those poor questions.

Comment: My bad. I just posted it as an approach that was indicated by OP.

Comment: No problem. I'm just trying to get the word out.  Cheers!